# Wide inverted breve overset

Tags: math-mode, symbols, typography, accents, stacking-symbols

I want an inverted breve that spans the width of two symbols rather than one.

I have tried the suggestions in:
[inverted breve accent in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38897/inverted-breve-accent-in-math-mode) , and in
[How to put \smallsmile or \smallfrown on top of a letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128625/how-to-put-smallsmile-or-smallfrown-on-top-of-a-letter/128626#128626).

But these were meant for inverted breve oversets that only span the width of one symbol.

Those suggestions give the top result below, whereas what I want is the bottom result below:

[image]

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make my image smaller ? It's bigger than my entire text ! But I couldn't figure out how to change the size ='(

Comment: `\usepackage{yhmath}` and `\wideparen` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `yhmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}
$\wideparen{\Delta k}+\wideparen{x+y+z}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This changes the math extension symbol font, so you may not want to do it; in this case you can just import the needed math accent

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{YHlargesymbols}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wideparen}{\mathord}{YHlargesymbols}{"F3}

\begin{document}
$\wideparen{\Delta k}+\wideparen{x+y+z}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly a parenthesis but...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abraces}
\begin{document}
\[
  \aoverbrace[L1R]{\triangle k}_{} \quad
  \aoverbrace[L1R]{\triangle k \nabla}_{}  \quad
  \aunderbrace[l1r]{\triangle k}_{}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I use `stackengine` package (`\stackon`) to stack the overset with the proper vertical separation, and the `scalerel` package (`\hstretch`) to horizontally stretch the `\smallfrown` to double its original width.  Increasing the `2` argument will make the overset wider still.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\( \stackon[0pt]{\Delta k}{\hstretch{2}{\smallfrown}} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I show a wider alternative, also more rounded, and set lower upon the symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\stackMath\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\begin{document}
\( \stackon[-2.1pt]{\Delta k}{\vstretch{1.3}{\hstretch{2.9}{\smallfrown}}} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]