# A circular version of \underbrace or \widehat

Tags: text-manipulation, circles

I'm new to LaTeX and am searching for a function that acts like `\underbrace` or `\widehat` but is circular (I don't want the pointed middle part). Does such a function exist? I tried using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) but I didn't find what I was looking for. I would be using it for text.

Comment: You can also use the abraces package as shown here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134068/wide-inverted-breve-overset

Comment: Or the `arcs` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the macro `\wideparen` from `yhmath` package could be a solution, but it is not really circular and it does not scale very well with the fontsize, in my point of view.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{yhmath}


\begin{document}
\[ \wideparen{E = mc^2}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to bring that curved line to the bottom?

Comment: @LiberatedDreamer: You asked for something like `\widehat`, that's above the text. You can try `\undergroup` from `MnSymbol{}` package

Comment: Thanks. I also found some more useful info here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15468/frown-and-mathop-stackrel-overset

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution that uses `pst-node`. I define an `\overarc` and an `underarc` commands, both with an optional argument, the angle between the arc and the chord determined by the extremities of the arc.

Unfortunately, for some reason, it doesn't work with `auto-pst-pdf`, so that you have to compile either with the chain `latex -> dvips -> pstopdf` or with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex, ifluatex}
\ifxetex\else \ifluatex\else\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\fi\fi
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\newcommand\overarc[2][30]{\psDefBoxNodes{F}{\mkern-2mu#2\mkern-2mu}\pcarc[offset=2pt, arcangle=#1]{c-c}(F:tl)(F:tr) }
\newcommand\underarc[2][30]{\psDefBoxNodes{F}{\mkern-2mu#2\mkern-2mu}\pcarc[offset=2pt, arcangle=#1]{c-c}(F:br)(F:bl) }

\begin{document}

\[ \overarc{E = mc²} \qquad \underarc{E = mc²} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]